# Resharper: Put opening parenthesis on new line

Tags: resharper

I've seen questions and answers about aligning closing parentheses with ReSharper, but in my case, I'd like to force the *opening* parenthesis to be on a new line.

For example:

```
Method(
    param1,
    param2
);
```

Would become:

```
Method
(
    param1,
    param2
);
```

I'm aware this style is unconventional, but because I'm working with CodeDOM, I'm creating a lot of tree-like constructs through method calls, so treating parentheses like curly braces would make the structure much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Found it right after posting...

Enabling all three checkboxes here does what I want:

- C# > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Arrangement of Invocations

  - Prefer wrap before "(" in invocation
  - Prefer wrap after "(" in invocation
  - Prefer wrap before ")" in invocation